# Como multiplicar corretamente o tipo decimal em C#?

Tags: c#, matemática, operadores, decimal

Estou fazendo multiplicação de valores monetários no C#, e para isso estou utilizando o tipo `decimal` para armazenar esses valores.

Notei que nele há um método chamado `Multiply()`, que recebe dois valores e realiza a multiplicação.

Porém fiquei em dúvida qual a utilidade dele, visto que para multiplicação basta apenas usarmos o operador `*`

Exemplo:

```
decimal multiplicacaoComMultiply = decimal.Multiply(50.40M, 3); 
decimal multiplicacaoComOperador = 50.40M * 3;

Console.WriteLine(multiplicacaoComMultiply);
Console.WriteLine(multiplicacaoComOperador);
```

O resultado será:

```
151,20 // Usando o multiply
151,20 // Usando o operador
```

#### Dúvidas

- Qual a utilidade deste método, visto que já temos o operador de multiplicação?
- Existe alguma perda de precisão utilizando o método ou o operador?
- Para trabalhar com multiplicação em que ambos os tipos são decimais, qual é o mais recomendado usar?

Segundo a [documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.decimal.multiply?view=netframework-4.7.2) deste método, ele não especifica o motivo ou diz que ele faz algo a mais do que o operador, como por exemplo de precisão.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Vamos olhar os fontes deles:

```
public static decimal Multiply(decimal d1, decimal d2) {
    DecCalc.VarDecMul(ref AsMutable(ref d1), ref AsMutable(ref d2));
    return d1;
}
```

[Fonte](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Decimal.cs,589).

```
public static decimal operator *(decimal d1, decimal d2) {
    DecCalc.VarDecMul(ref AsMutable(ref d1), ref AsMutable(ref d2));
    return d1;
}
```

[Fonte](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Decimal.cs,995).

Eles são idênticos na sua concepção. Não sei se propositalmente ou não, mas o código é o mesmo (não sei se não deveria ter uma abstração aí para ser mais [DRY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101) e garantir que sempre faz o mesmo e não tenha problema de alguém alterar um e não o outro sem querer, mas pode ser que realmente um dia alguém pode querer que seja diferente, apesar de improvável). Mas eles não são idênticos em toda sua semântica por causa de regras da linguagem, já falo abaixo

> Qual a utilidade deste método, visto que já temos o operador de multiplicação?

Difícil afirmar. Pode ser que só para dar simetria com outras coisas. Mas existe uma diferença que pode ser um motivo para usar um ou outro:

```
using static System.Console;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        WriteLine(decimal.Multiply(50.40M, 3));
        WriteLine(50.40M * 3);
//      WriteLine(decimal.Multiply(50.40, 3));
        WriteLine(50.40 * 3);
        WriteLine(decimal.Multiply(50, 3).GetType());
        WriteLine((50 * 3).GetType());
//      decimal x = 1_000_000 * 1_000_000;
        decimal x = decimal.Multiply(1_000_000, 1_000_000);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/0hUDgt). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/AtyAa9). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Decimal/MultyplyOpAndMethod.cs).

Experimente tirar o comentário. Dá erro. Pode ser que você queira garantir que o tipo não seja promovido automaticamente, ou seja, só pode usar um valor que seja genuinamente `decimal`, não apenas um que pode ser convertido para. Com o operador a regra da linguagem é permitir que a promoção ocorre, com o método isto não ocorre, não há promoção direta estabelecida de todos tipos numéricos para `decimal`.

E note o tipo de cada expressão. Com o método garantimos que o resultado será `decimal`, com o operador depende, se um dos dados não for `decimal` o resultado não será `decimal´. A regra de sobrecarga do operador tem ambiguidade e a preferência é resolver pelo tipo natural e não um que possa ser promovido, nem poderia ser diferente.

No último você multiplica 2 números grandes e estira a capacidade. Claro que se fossem literais do tipo `decimal` (que terminam com `M`) não haveria problema. Mas mesmo usando inteiros no método dá certo justamente por causa da promoção que de `int` para `decimal` ocorre. No caso do operador será invocado o operador de `int` que não suporta números tão grandes e depois de calcular é que o resultado seria promovido para `decimal`, mas tarde demais.

Tudo isso é um problema de resolução, não que um se comporta diferente do outro no que ele se propõe fazer, mas o que é chamado em cada situação.

> Existe alguma perda de precisão utilizando o método ou o operador?

Não, são idênticos. E como nada disto está documentado não podem mudar isto depois.

> Para trabalhar com multiplicação em que ambos os tipos são decimais, qual é o mais recomendado usar?

O mais legível para a situação, duvido que tenha um caso que não seja o operador.

Comment: Na documentação do operador `*` para a estrutura [`Decimal`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.op_multiply?view=netframework-4.7.2) afirma que tanto o método como o operador são equivalentes e que o método é uma alternativa para linguagens que não dão suporte a operadores personalizados. Só não sei informar qual a linguagem .Net que não dá esse suporte.

Comment: @AugustoVasques isto é um bom motivo de interoperabilidade mesmo, não acredito que criaram só por isto, mas também por isto, não afeta o C#, mas pode ajudar essas outras linguagens. Eu não citei porque como tem a documentação que o AP viu achei que isto ele já tinha conhecimento.